# Unresolved package "generated" in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my Android Studio `androidManifest.xml` file, I found an unresolved package `generated`. How can I fix it?

The issued code is : `android:name=".provider.generated.SquawkProvider`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.aaa">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<provider
    android:name=".provider.generated.SquawkProvider"
     <!--  shows unresolved package "generated" -->

    android:authorities="com.example.android.aaa.provider.provider"
    android:exported="false" >
</provider>

<activity
    android:name=".following.FollowingPreferenceActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>

<service
    android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove the line `<!--  shows unresolved package "generated" -->` and close the `"` after `SquawkProvider`.

Comment: closing the " in the end was inserted, but not listed here. the line <!-- shows unresolved package "generated" -->  was just for explanation, Thanks

Comment: Has a solution been found to this, because I've got this too?  I don't quite understand what the .generated is doing.  My provider is in java/provider folder, so why generated?

If I remove generated the error I get is:
'android.example.com.squawker.provider.SquawkProvider' is not assignable to 'android.content.ContentProvider'.  I'm unsure why that's so.

Help gratefully received.

Answer (score 23):

This issue stems from annotation processing now being included in Gradle from version 2.2. You can fix project and get it running with the following changes.

Project level "*build.gradle*" remove this line:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
```

App level "*build.gradle*" remove this line:

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

and change this line replacing `apt` with `annotationProcessor`:

```
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

In build.gradle(Module:app)
remove this  two line

1) Top on the file

```
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

2) in dependencies

```
apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
```

add this

```
annotationProcessor 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above responses don't work for you, make sure you are using the latest version of Android Studio and gradle plugin (4.4 as of this post) and have changed all the 'compile' lines with 'implementation'.

After that try Build -> Clean Project then Build -> Rebuild Project. (All of this after following @drspaceboo's answer of deleting classpath and plugin lines, then changing apt to annotationProcessor.)

Answer (score -4):

**Try this:-**

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and then Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: I'm not expert in programming and computing.   Would you explain more detail how I can go to the file, invalidate caches and restart ?

Comment: Open Android Studio . See the menu bar. Click on "File" menu.

Comment: Thanks Ankita, I found the menu - Invalidate Caches /Restart  and did Invalidate and Restart.   But still it unresolved. ...